# Can a container have other containers within it?

Tags: docker

I'm fairly new to docker. This is to say that I can spin containers up and down and get into them and do stuff with them but I've yet to build my own container. My question is, can a docker container, contain other containers? For example, if I want a cluster of 3 Kafka servers, can I do that in 3 docker containers and then put all of them in a container?

Comment: You can run docker in docker (I think), but... what would be the point?

Comment: Same as always. Encapsulation and ease-of-use.  Example, you work only on component X but interact with 15 other components in a complex environment.  Put them all in one container with all the interactions between them that don't involve your component pre-configured.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, but first please read [Docker-in-Docker](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/)

For your specific use case you can use [service_scale](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_scale/). Probably you are using compose, so check [scale](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/scale/)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is called [orchestration](https://www.docker.com/products/orchestration). There are several products which you can use, the most used and supported one would be [docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) or [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/).

Approaches like *docker-in-docker (DinD)* are mostly useful for running Continuous Integration pipelines where you just need some very simple orchestration in an isolated environment (Docker).

I suggest trying to look into `docker-compose` for local development, Kubernetes for the production environment and DinD/Kubernetes for your pipelines.